# Reflection for async api

Tags: java, asynchronous, reflection, api-design

We have 2 services, lets call then S and G. S has a series of steps say a,b,c,d,e,f and at step d it makes a call to service G. G often takes a lot of time (spanning over minutes) to process the call leading to lots of timeout issues. To solve this we are planning to make G's APIs asynchronous. G has almost 20 APIs which need to made as async. I have 2 questions while designing this:

1. the ideal way to make these async would be to use SQS or SNS topic and make S listen on them. But this is an intrusive change and would require lots of refactoring of code, in this case splitting the steps a,b,c,d,e,f. We are looking for something fast. Hence we are planning to store the request id in some key value store and let G's API return a success after basic sanity checks and in the background keep processing the request. As soon as it is done, the result is updated in the key-value store and meanwhile G keeps polling the store at regular intervals. Does this look like a correct approach?
2. To make G's APIs asynchronous we would have to change/write whole lot of code for all 20 APIs. I was thinking of exposing one single API which uses reflection to identify which method to call at runtime. I know about problems associated with reflection such as no compile-time error detection, hard to refactor, slower performance and since we are introducing reflection in API facing outside clients there would be a lot of problem doing sanity checks of the method name being passed. The only pro is it makes my code a lot cleaner with minimal interference.

I would like to know what should be my way ahead to solve the above problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making G's APIs asynchronous does not makes it fast. It only allows to run it in parallel with the steps e and f. If that steps do not take much time, then the overall time will not be decreased significantly.

So the first question you need to answer is whether parallelization can help at all. If your task is mainly sequential, then parallelization would not help, and can even make things slower. If your task can be parallelized, you represent it as an execution graph.

When you decide that parallelization makes sense, then you can choose, for each parallel branch, will it be implemented as a thread or as an asynchronous procedure call (APC). Threads are easier to program, but consume some amount of memory (0.5-1.0 megabytes per thread). Usually asynchronous programming is worth to apply if you have hundreds and thousands of parallel branches in your execution graph. I cannot see so much parallelizm in your task, so I recommend use threads instead of asynchronous procedures.

And never employ polling - both multithreading and asyncronous programming have enough means to react to events in time.

As for the second question, some manual work is required anyway. Suppose you have API:

```
interface SyncApi {
    boolean isPositive(int v1);
    int sum(int v1, int v2);
}
```

then you have to write

```
interface AsyncApi {
    Future<Boolean> isPositive(int v1);
    Future <Integer> sum(int v1, int v2);
}
```

You can make a tool which creates AsyncApi.java  when fed up with SyncApi.java, but anyway you need AsyncApi interface at compile time, to be able to write a call to that interface.

An adapter to create an instance of AsyncApi when given an instance of SyncApi, can be created at run time using [Java Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) machinery.

Comment: I agree that it is not making it fast but it helps increase the availability of the system. We are not sure yet what impact parallelizing would have on the business use case. S is does not get a lot of requests and hence we can afford the thread to wait for some time till the result is processed.  Also what are your views on the second question?

Comment: So you don't support the use of reflection here?

Comment: @katherine class Proxy is a part of reflection package. I mean, if you want to use reflection, then I suggest to use java.lang.reflect.Proxy.